# Web-Scrape , looking for better way to get class or tag xpath and dynamic webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

This is my web **scrape** target site.
https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&SearchText=ipad&SortType=default&g=n&page=1

With this code, I can get 60 items.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument('--lang=en')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'c:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36")
url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&SearchText=ipad&SortType=default&g=n&page=1'
driver.get(url)
sleep(1)
y = 1000
for timer in range(0, 13):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(y) + ")")
    y += 1000
    time.sleep(1)

items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "_2E_KG")]')
print(len(items))
```

I found out that this web page is dynamic, so I added scrolling like this.

```
for timer in range(0, 13):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(y) + ")")
    y += 1000
    time.sleep(1)
```

It's a little slow, but it looks good to me.
Or do you have a better idea of doing this?

And use xpath finding as below to get the item.

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "_2E_KG")]')
```

[image]

But I believe that one day the class name (_2E_KG) will change, and I want to put in a stable xpath, but I don't know what it will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get the XPath with dev tool, as shown below :

[image]

Result will be `//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]`, delete `[1]` at the end and you have your XPath dynamically!

Comment: I am trying get product title using xpath with your way(copy xpath), then I get "//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/span/text()". title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/span/text()'), print(title), but I didn't get text. Do you know why? This is error message I get. invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/span/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: Try with **Copy full XPath** option, I think selenium can't process `*[@id="root"]`. You should have something like this : `/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div`

Comment: I tried items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div'), title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[1]/div[1]/a/span').text. it works. Anyway thank you.